# Displaying and downloading a pdf in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, blob

I am using wix and in order to customize any html you need to use an embed object which creates a sandboxed iframe on the site.  I have a decent grasp of how this works and posting messages to it but what I am having difficulties with is generating a pdf into this iframe.

I have done some reading and I think I get the overall concept.  While traditionally you would just set the source to some document on a server somewhere I am generating the content dynamically based on user action.  So it looks like something like pdfkit and creating a blob is the way to go.

I think I am able to generate the pdf without issues as well as a blob url no problem

[![console image][1]][1]

I can manually open the console and get that URL and paste it in the browser and the document opens exactly how I expect it.  However I can't get it to display normally in the browser.

I have tried setting the src of various elements = to the blob url without luck.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  blah
 <script src="https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/releases/download/v0.11.0/pdfkit.standalone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream/releases/download/v0.1.3/blob-stream.js">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    const doc = new PDFDocument
    const stream = doc.pipe(blobStream())
    
    doc.fontSize(25).text('Testing document', 100, 80);
    console.log(doc);
     doc.end();
stream.on('finish', function() {
  window.src = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');
  a.download = 'ShoppingList' || 'download';
  console.log("download IS",a)
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition to setting the window.src I have tried document.src iframe.src which returns an error.
displaying isn't strictly necessary but a download link would be.  Is there some other way I can do this to get this data?  I feel I am missing something very simple.

I have had to change the examples as given on [http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html][2] but I don't think this is any issue as the package is working as expected and the document is being created.

Edit:
I have made some progress on this but am getting stuck in downloading it.  What I did was these 2 things.

```
<input type="button" id = "dload" onclick="location.href='';" value="Download Shopping List" />

document.getElementById("dload").onclick = function(){location.href = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf')};
```

the pdf actually shows in the iframe as expected with the full capabilities of a pdf preview however the download doesn't work at all it just says failed - network error and the filetype is not a pdf which makes sense.  Is there something else I can add to get this working?

Edit2: Tried one more thing that doesn't work very well since popups are mostly blocked

```
window.open(stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf'), '_blank');
```

this, while it technically works is really messy and is causing a number of problems.  Also it works differently on mobile vs desktop.  There has to be some simple way to just show a pdf but it seems to just result in more questions the more I search.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/le6o9.png
[2]: http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partially solved my question and it is good enough for what I need.  Here is what I did.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/releases/download/v0.11.0/pdfkit.standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/devongovett/blob-stream/releases/download/v0.1.3/blob-stream.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data) {
            // create a document and pipe to a blob
            var doc = new PDFDocument();
            var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());
            doc.font('Helvetica');
              doc.fontSize(20);
              doc.text('Some Text',200,20);              

              // end and display the document in the iframe to the right
              doc.end();
            stream.on('finish', function() {
                const blob = stream.toBlob('application/pdf')
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.download = "YourFileName";
                a.style.position = 'fixed';
                a.target = '_blank';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            });
      };
    };
    </script>
  </head>  
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

while I can't see the pdf using this method it does download correctly which was the more important piece.  Technically I could combine the two but since the download button on the iframe doesn't work I think it would be confusing for someone having a separate button to actually download it.  So I have a separate button outside the frame that triggers the "onmessage" it is a function of wix.  This triggers all document generation and download.